# Laravel 5 NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5

I have created a PostController with an index function having this one line of code

```
return view('welcome'); // I have welcome.blade.php inside views folder
```

I have also put this on my Route file

```
Route::get('post', 'PostController@index');
```

When I try to access /post on the browser, I get '**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 145:**' error message.

What gives?

**Edit:** Here is PostController.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();

        return view('welcome', compact($posts));
    }
```

Comment: Show us the PostController, specifically the namespace at the top and the index function.

Comment: Does `php artisan route:list` show the route you're trying to access?

Comment: Did you try running `composer dump`?

Comment: I have re-installed it and now it is working

Answer (score -1):

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();

    return view('welcome', compact('posts'));
}
```

creo que tiene que corregir el compoct `view('welcome', compact($posts));` a

```
return view('welcome', compact('posts'));
```